# Why are the functions inside the integral integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, absolute-continuity

Here is the question :

Let $f$ and $g$ be absolutely continuous functions on $[a,b]$. Show that $$\int_{a}^{b} fg^{'} = f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a) - \int_{a}^{b} f^{'}g.$$

**My trial:**

Let $f$ and $g$ be absolutely continuous functions on $[a,b].$ since the product of absolutely continuous functions is an absolutely continuous function(I know how to prove this ). Therefore, by theorem 10 on pg.124 in Royden and Fitzpatrick (4th edition)$$\int_{a}^{b} (fg)^{'} = f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a).$$ But $(fg)^{'} = f^{'}g  + fg^{'}$ using the product rule, then distribute the integral sign over the previous 2 terms and then by linearity of integration for integrable functions we can  get the result.

**My question is:**

Why $f^{'}g$ and  $fg^{'}$ are integrable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute continuity implies that $f'$ is integrable. Since $g$ is bounded it follows that $f'g$ is integrable.

Comment: Was this result "the product of integrable and bounded functions is integrable" proved in Royden?

Comment: was it proved in Royden ? if so at which page?

Comment: $\int |f'(x)g(x)|dx \leq M \int |f'(x)|dx <\infty$ where $M$ is the supremum  of $|g|$.

Comment: Sorry for this trivial question but why is $g$ bounded?

Comment: Is this because it is continuous on a closed interval so it attains its maximum and minimum ? is this result valid also for Lebesgue measurable functions?

Comment: @Emptymind Yes, every continuous function on $[a,b]$ is bounded.